# Not Getting the list data in json responce when i am using the asp.net web api in mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

This is my Javascript in my Project

```
  function GetData() {
                debugger;
                var url = 'http://localhost:50951/api/Home';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Success Message");
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert("Error Message");
                    }
                });
        }
```

And this is my WebApi code

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
            {
                public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Index()
                {
                    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> listString = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("India","India"),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("Australia","Australia"),
                    };
                    return listString;
                }
            }
```

When i Firing the `GetData` function, API is calling and it returns the list.But in javascript its showing Error message.Its is not enter into success.
Is there any way to get the list data in josn response when using API.

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: return it in json

Comment: responsetext is empty

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting using `Get` method so there must need a `Get` method in web api, either rename the `Index()` as `Get()` or use a `[HttpGet]` attribute before the `Index()` method to indicate it get like below

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
       {
          [HttpGet]
          [Route("api/Home")]
          public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Index()
          {
              List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> listString = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
              {
                  new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("India","India"),
                  new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("Australia","Australia"),
              };
              return listString;
           }
       }
```

and the url

```
var url = '/api/Home';
```

Comment: Even when i am using [HttpGet] not getting output.still it is enter into  error: function (error) {
                        alert("Error Message");
                    }

Comment: small clarification, Why i need to give  [Route("api/Home")]..? when i call the api from javascript, api is calling and it returns list. But in javascript it does't goto succuss function.

Comment: Here i took two projects.one for my project and another one for webapis.